# How to set up vscode to close window for tags in html?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The window in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xyvI.png)

Comment: Your photo only shows <div> tags. These tags allow you to apply specific styling traits to the elements enclosed within them when you either: 1) assign a class or ID to the div tag and reference it in your CSS style sheet, or 2) specify the styling traits within the div tag directly. It does not directly support the question you are trying to ask us - perhaps you meant to ask us how to make VS Code automatically add closing tags when you type in an opening tag.

Comment: I think he is referring to the popup dialog about what a div is (when you hover over an element for example).  I originally thought setting parameterHints to false would get rid of those but it does not.  I tried a couple of other settings but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to ask us how to set up Visual Studio Code to automatically add closing tags to XML elements such as the  element shown in the picture, afaik I don't think the software features this kind of functionality built in. You might have to go the way of using add-ons, such as these two:

- [Auto Close Tag for Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/formulahendry/2016/06/29/auto-close-tag-for-visual-studio-code/)
- [Auto Close Tag by Jun
  Han](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag)

A web search could easily bring up a couple more. Go ahead and give it a try; if it isn't what you want, please edit your question and make it clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some further research, there is an open issue on getting more control over those hover popups see [disable hover in editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19988).

The suggestion is to use the undocumented setting:

```
"editor.hover": false,
```

which works **after** a restart of vscode.  You must restart vscode to get it to work.  Unfortunately that applies to all files of any kind and

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.hover": false,
}
```

**does not work** so you have to use just

```
"editor.hover": false,
```

instead.